# JavaScript Loop Function With typed.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use the typed.js function to create a loop.
https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/

```
<span id="typed"></span>
<script>
 var options = {
      strings: ["First sentence", "Second sentence"],
      typeSpeed: 40,
    }
    var typed = new Typed("#typed", options);
    loop: true
</script>
```

the strings label is what will be typed out.
Currently nothing is showing up for this.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/

Comment: I did read through the document, but it requires me to install something I don't want to install. I think I may be using an older version of the JS document provided.

Comment: I guessed that is the plugin you are using. Pretty hard to guess off a random file name.

Comment: I got the most recent file from the typed.js site. Now it doesn't pop up anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try writing

```
<span id="typed"></span>
<script>
 var options = {
      strings: ["First sentence", "Second sentence"],
      typeSpeed: 40,
      loop: true
    }
    var typed = new Typed("#typed", options);
</script>
```

Check your browser's console you might be having error for your code.